# What's a good resource for learning OpenRefine?

Tags: openrefine

The book, [Using OpenRefine](http://www.packtpub.com/openrefine-guide-for-data-analysis-and-linking-dataset-to-the-web/book), has been a really good resource, but is there anything better?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an actual question here.  Are you looking for something more simple than the book you've been using?

Comment: @Joe Actually yes!

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://openrefine.org/documentation.html) page on OpenRefine website point out to the official wiki a list of tutorials and the discussion list for your project specific questions.

Like @Joe pointed out, I am not sure what are your looking for exactly. Maybe you can explain what you are tying to learn and why the book or existing documentation doesn't address your challenge.

(disclaimer I am part of the OpenRefine team)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [these three videos](https://code.google.com/p/google-refine) if you like watching tutorials.

Otherwise the list mentioned by @magdmartin is quite extensive.